# The convergence of an integral, dependant on a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

I have to say if the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x}\,dx$$
that depends on the parameter $y$ is convergent (I don't know the right terminology, since I'm not studying in english, but I will provide the criterion for such convergence) when 1) $y\in (0,1)$ and 2) $y\in [1,\infty]$. The criterion we use to determine such convergence is as follows:
If
$$\lim_{b\rightarrow +\infty}\sup_{y\in D}\left | \int_b^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x} \, dx \right |=0$$
where $D$ is the domain of parameter $y$ then we say that the integral converges properly when $y$ is in that domain. The problem is, I have no idea how to integrate that function. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: The integral is obviously convergent if $\Re (y) >0$, and divergent otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology you are looking for is **uniform convergence**, and you have provided a necessary and sufficient condition for the uniform convergence of an improper integral depending on a parameter $y \in D$, viz.

$$\lim_{b \to \infty}\sup_{y \in D} \left|\int_b^\infty f(x,y)\, dx\right| = 0$$

In case (2), we have $\left| \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x}\right| \leqslant e^{-x}$ for all $y \in [1,\infty)$. Since $\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \, dx = 1 < \infty$ we have uniform convergence of the improper intergral for $y \in [1,\infty)$ by the Weierstrass M-test.

In case (1), we have

$$\sup_{y \in (0,1)} \left|\int_b^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x}\, dx\right| \geqslant \sup_{y \in (0,1)}\int_b^{2b} \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x}\, dx \geqslant \sup_{y \in (0,1)} b \cdot \frac{e^{-2by}}{1+2b} \geqslant \underbrace{\frac{b}{1+2b}e^{-2}}_{y = 1/b}, $$

and, hence,

$$\lim_{b\to \infty}\sup_{y \in (0,1)} \left|\int_b^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x}\,dx \right|\geqslant \lim_{b \to \infty}\frac{b}{1+2b}e^{-2} = \frac{e^{-2}}{2} \neq 0$$

Therefore, convergence is not uniform for $y \in (0,1)$.

Comment: Thank you! What would you do if the question was the same, but the denominator of the integrand was $1+x^{2}$ and $y \geq 0$? I can't seem to figure this one out even when using your solution as an example...

Comment: Hey, nevermind, figured it out! Chose $y=0$ when taking the sup and got 0

Comment: @DDomjosa: You're welcome.  Note that with  $x \geqslant 0$, $\left| \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x^2}\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ for all $y \geqslant 0$, and $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^2} = \frac{\pi}{2} < \infty$. By the Weierstrass M-test the convergence is uniform in this case for all $y \geqslant 0$.  The previous argument I used to prove non-uniform convergence for $y \in (0,1)$ does not apply because you get a RHS $\frac{b e^{-2}}{1 + 4b^2}$ and this approaches $0$ as $b \to \infty$.

Comment: This tells us nothing useful about $\sup_{y \in (0,1)} \left|\int_b^\infty \frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x^2}\, dx\right|$ because the RHS is a lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

I would adress the problem this way: if $y=0$ then the integrand behaves like $$g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$$ (you can try to integrate $g$ and use the definition of indefinite integral) and therefore the integral diverges. If $y>0$, since $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{-xy} x^2}{1+x} =0\text{,}$$ then there is $M$ such that for each $x > M$ then
$$\frac{e^{-xy}}{1+x}<\frac{1}{x^2}\text{.}$$
Thus the integral converge (you can try to apply the defintion to $x^{-2}$ and use a suitable squeeze theorem. Do you know about that?). Finally, if $y<0$ then you are integrating
$$\frac{e^{\vert y \vert x}}{1+x}$$ which surely diverges! (Think about that and feel free to ask if you are not sure). Hope this helped.